# fail to redirect user to specific jsp page from login using servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect

```
try {
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String lEmail="";
        String lPassword="";
        String type="";
        String doc="Doctor";
        String pat="Patient";
        ResultSet rs;

        try{
          String sql;
          sql = "SELECT lEmail, lPassword, userType FROM tblLogin ";

          rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                if(rs.next())
                {
                    lEmail = rs.getString("lEmail");
                    lPassword = rs.getString("lPassword");
                    type = rs.getString("userType");
                }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
```

There are 3 conditions for user:
email id , password , userType. Is there any problem with those conditions or is it inside the try/catch block or if else condition is not correct?

```
        if(txtId.equals(lEmail) && txtPassword.equals(lPassword)&& doc.equals(Type)){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("doctor.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else if(txtId.equals(lEmail) && txtPassword.equals(lPassword)&&Type.equals(pat)){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("patientView.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{  
            out.println("Your Id and Password do not match");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem here is you are forwarding your dispatcher twice ( even it is commited once). in your servlet you can use `.forward(req,res)` only once.

what you can do is, assign your page url to a string variable and at the end of the conditional block, you forward it only once using the string variable you set.

```
String url="";
if(txtId.equals(lEmail) && txtPassword.equals(lPassword)&& doc.equals(Type)){
           url = "doctor.jsp";
        }else if(txtId.equals(lEmail) && txtPassword.equals(lPassword)&&Type.equals(pat)){
           url = "patientView.jsp";
        }else{
           url = "errorPage.jsp" /* if you have any */  
           out.println("Your Id and Password do not match");
        }
request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
```

now you can see, I have used the dispatcher only once. try this way and see.